# How to identify which files are missing in Solr indexing

Tags: solr, solr4

I am using Solr 4.1 on my computer. I am seeing Num Docs:10961 and Max Doc:10961 in the core dashboard. After observing the source folder in the computer, there are 10965 i.e. 4 files more than the indexed files. There must be the equal number of the file in both Solr and folder on my computer. Now I have a task to identify the missing files and REPOST them for indexing. The indexed documents id (always unique for each document) is full path of the physical location such as

"id":"E:\ABCFolder\1\test file.pdf"

I need someone's help for the following question:

What is the way to find out the missing files in indexing and source files which were posted?

**Note:** One boring method that I know is search for each file name in the source folder to the Solr query window and see if the file is present.

Comment: What have you tried? This can be answered by any small script that can loop through a directory and issue a query to Solr to check if the document is present.

Comment: What have you used to index the files ?
I may state the obvious, but have you checked the logs ?
It is likely that your 4 missing docs had some invalid content for the related fields.